# Javascript + Browser - How to detect when dev tools / firebug is open?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web

Before anyone of you starts saying it's impossible, please navigate to facebook.com open the devtools, **even in non attached mode**, and it will tell you that dev tools is opened, right?

So how is facebook able to pull that off?

I am able to do it for attached windows

```
window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight > 200 || window.outerWidth - window.innerWidth > 200
```

But when the window is popped up, this doesn't work.

**How is facebook able to pull this off?**

Comment: My guess they put that console warning upfront. You just don't see it up until you open the dev tools. I'm not sure I understand why do you need to know if the devtool is open.

Comment: @elpddev, you were right, it is just `console.log` with some fancy formatting. See my answer if you care to see the code they use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @[elpddev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3625171/elpddev) speculated in the comments, they are just using `console.log` to log it when the page loads, they are not detecting that you have opened the console.

If you examine the JS code on the page you should find this:

```
var j = i.stop || h._("Stop!")
  , k = i.text || h._("This is a browser feature intended for developers. If someone told you to copy-paste something here to enable a Facebook feature or \"hack\" someone's account, it is a scam and will give them access to your Facebook account.")
  , l = i.more || h._("See {url} for more information.", [h.param('url', 'https://www.facebook.com/selfxss')]);
if ((window.chrome || window.safari) && !i.textonly) {
    var m = 'font-family:helvetica; font-size:20px; ';
    [[j, i.c1 || m + 'font-size:50px; font-weight:bold; ' + 'color:red; -webkit-text-stroke:1px black;'], [k, i.c2 || m], [l, i.c3 || m], ['', '']].map(function(s) {
        setTimeout(console.log.bind(console, '\n%c' + s[0], s[1]));
    });
} else {
    var n = ['', ' .d8888b.  888                       888', 'd88P  Y88b 888                       888', 'Y88b.      888                       888', ' "Y888b.   888888  .d88b.  88888b.   888', '    "Y88b. 888    d88""88b 888 "88b  888', '      "888 888    888  888 888  888  Y8P', 'Y88b  d88P Y88b.  Y88..88P 888 d88P', ' "Y8888P"   "Y888  "Y88P"  88888P"   888', '                           888', '                           888', '                           888']
      , o = ('' + k).match(/.{35}.+?\s+|.+$/g)
      , p = Math.floor(Math.max(0, (n.length - o.length) / 2));
    for (var q = 0; q < n.length || q < o.length; q++) {
        var r = n[q];
        n[q] = r + new Array(45 - r.length).join(' ') + (o[q - p] || '');
    }
    console.log('\n\n\n' + n.join('\n') + '\n\n' + l + '\n');
    return;
}
```

It's a little hard to read since it is minified, even with pretty printing. The `j = i.stop || h._("Stop!")` type stuff appears to be trying to load localized text, falling back to English. It then test to see if they have detected the browser as Chrome or Safari and `i.textonly` is not set, if so it appears to be displaying it with the fancy styling you get when viewing it in Chrome/Safari. The `else` clause is harder to follow but it appears to create the ASCII art banner you get in text mode or non-Chrome/Safari browsers:

```
 .d8888b.  888                       888    
d88P  Y88b 888                       888    
Y88b.      888                       888    This is a browser feature intended for 
 "Y888b.   888888  .d88b.  88888b.   888    developers. If someone told you to copy-paste 
    "Y88b. 888    d88""88b 888 "88b  888    something here to enable a Facebook feature 
      "888 888    888  888 888  888  Y8P    or "hack" someone's account, it is a 
Y88b  d88P Y88b.  Y88..88P 888 d88P         scam and will give them access to your 
 "Y8888P"   "Y888  "Y88P"  88888P"   888    Facebook account.
                           888              
                           888              
                           888              

See https://www.facebook.com/selfxss for more information.
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what facebook has done is just logged the warning in Console.
Below is the code that worked for me in Chrome.
I disabled 3 ways I know to start Developer Tool in Chrome:

1. Right Click and select Inspect option: For this, I disabled Right Click
2. F12 Key Press: blocked this event's default behavior
3. Ctrl + Shift + I: blocked all Ctrl default behavior

See, if you can afford this.

```
document.onkeydown = function(event) {      
    if(event.code == "F12" || event.ctrlKey) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', event => event.preventDefault());
```